# Conflict between jQuery and Javascript scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, conflict

I have these two scripts into my website. The first one makes the #top section to fade out when it scrolls out of the viewport, while the second script makes #top to change its background-color according to the time of the day.

The first script worked perfectly until I added the second one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 1) {
            $("#top").addClass("scrolled");
        } else {
            $("#top").removeClass("scrolled");
        }
    });
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var now = new Date();
  var hours = now.getHours();

  // 1:00 AM to 6:00 AM
  if (hours > 1 && hours < 6) {
    document.getElementById("top").style.backgroundColor = "#feed9f"
  }
  // 7:00 AM to 12:00 PM
  else if (hours > 7 && hours < 12) {
    document.getElementById("top").style.backgroundColor = "#fee36c"
  }
  // 1:00 PM to 6:00 PM
  else if (hours > 13 && hours < 18) {
    document.getElementById("top").style.backgroundColor = "#fdda3a";
  }
  // 7:00 PM to 12:00 AM
  else if (hours > 19 && hours < 24) {
    document.getElementById("top").style.backgroundColor = "#fdd007";
  }
</script>
```

At the moment the first script is in the `<head>` while the second is placed at the bottom of `<body>` (works only this way).

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: With the scripts put this way, only the second one works (so the page changes color according to the time of the day, but it doesn't fade out when scrolled)

Comment: Have you used the browser debugging tools to see if the first script actually does add the class? It could be that the change to the `style` in the second script overrides the CSS rules for the class manipulated by the first script.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, on my CSS I just added !important to my .scrolled class and now both scripts work perfectly!